# How to measure electrical resistance?

Tags: electricity, physical-chemistry, electric-current

Is it possible to theoretically measure the resistance of passing of electrical current through liquid electrolyte (distilled water + NaOH) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and indeed this is absolutely routine. In fact one of the more interesting projects I've done recently was to develop software to calculate the conductivity of electrolyte solutions in nuclear power station cooling circuits (I did it as an Excel spreadsheet - that's how powerful excel is these days!). See the Wikipedia article on the [conductivity of electrolytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductivity_%28electrolytic%29) for more info.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you send me that software if it is freeware? :)

Comment: My client paid me £10k to write it, and I doubt they'd approve :-) I have to dash now, but tomorrow I'll edit my answer to show how the calculation is done.